# Combine the rewrite rule and proxy pass in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Now I have two rules for two types of requests:

1. `GET http://host:3000?k1=v1&k2=v2` passed to `GET http://host:4000/messages/verify?k1=v1&k2=v2` to handle.
2. `POST http://host:3000` passed to `POST http://host:4000/messages/push` to handle, meanwhile the post data also passed.